# C# WindowsForms two combobox connected

Tags: c#

I'm writing an pipe calculator app. My purpose is to connect one ComboBox with another to change the displayed values, but I have no idea how to do it. Both ComboBoxes are filled from two diffrent lists. I think maybe the way is to use switch case, but the code is bigger then. Any suggestions to make it simple?

For instance: Combox1=DN6, ComboBox2= 1,6; 1,8  Combox1=DN8, ComboBox2= 1,8; 2,0 etc.

[Winform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHlox.png)

Edit:
In short: I have two lists, one for each ComboBox. When I select from the first ComboBox1 drop-down list, I want it to display the selected range in the second ComboBox2 to choose from in second one. Basicly change values range depending on what is selected in ComboBox1.

Comment: Sorry, but your problem is unclear... Can you be more specific and provide more informations about "connection" between comboboxes?

Comment: How _exactly_ do you want them to be connected? Does the first item in Combobox1 correspond to the first item in Combobox2 and so on? If not, please [edit] the question and elaborate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are referring to the "change" event of the 1st combox affecting the second one. In other words when you selected a value in the first combo it then fills the values in the 2nd. Is that correct?